# Weblogic: Binary file is rendered instead of downloading

Tags: weblogic, mime-types

I am having a html file which has anchor tag linking to the binary file in same ear. Problem is when I am clicking on anchor tag, the binary file is rendered instead of prompting for download or download. Doesnt have problem when using apache. Tried specifying mimetype in anchor tag by using attribute *content-type="application/octet-stream"* but didnt help.

Environment used is weblogic linux.

Answer (score 0):

I think we need to configure mime-type at the server level rather than @ anchor tags as server first would recognize the mime-type extension to service the download

Ref
https://blogs.oracle.com/brunoborges/entry/ohs_and_apk_files